# Is the sum over state space of A in P(A|B) equal to 1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This seems like an obvious question but I can't seem to find any lemma online or in my probability textbook stating it. Basically I am wondering if the following statement is true:

$$
\sum_{a\in A} P(a|B) = 1
$$

For some event B, not independent of A.

Any insight or links to a proof would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if $A$ is a discrete set then $\sum_{a \in A} P(\{a\} \mid B) = P(A \mid B)$, which is not necessarily $1$.

What is true is that $P(\cdot \mid B)$ is a probability measure, so in particular $\sum_{b \in B} P(\{b\} \mid B) = 1$.